# Need to send Power Bi report visual in mail on scheduling

Tags: email, outlook, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

Need to send report visual not just link .
I have tried with 'Subscribe to report' option but it has limited text and tried Power automate but getting Ultra low DLP error.
is there any other ways to send power bi report visual in outlook.

Comment: On what license are you on? Power BI Pro license?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani -Yes Pro license

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve so.

- If you are coming from SSRS I suppose you were doing something similar before: downloading the PDFs on a folder and a script was then sending them to the right receiver. You can do the same and use the [Power BI API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/file-download-api) to [export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file) the files to a specific folder.
- As you said before you can use the automatic subscription and just enable the [Attach full report](https://www.popautomation.com/post/power-bi-automated-emails#:%7E:text=To%20automatically%20e%2Dmail%20a,e%2Dmail%20should%20be%20sent.) feature
- You can use [Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export) to setup a logic that will send the report with attachment to the right receiver

Comment: Firstly we don’t have to use SSRS
And we can’t attach full report as it is pro license and I tried power automate too but getting company data loss policy error.

Comment: none of the 3 options I gave you is related to SSRS in any way. I just mentioned SSRS because what I wanted to say is "you have with Power BI the same way to export PDS as you had with SSRS".